# Antibiotic resistant genes

Tags: antibiotic-resistance

Can someone help me find be it an article or journal that has the conventional PCR method for the detection of antibiotic resistant genes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have in mind any specific antibiotic resistence gene? Which antibiotic?

Comment: I tested my isolated bacteria against 10 antibiotics, namely: Tetracycline, vancomycin, cephalothin, ciproflaxin, chloramphenicol, ampicillin, erythromycin, kanamycin,trimethoprim, and neomycin.